# Why does XMLHttpRequest/XHR and Fetch API work locally in Firefox 51?

Tags: javascript, firefox

**Update: As of Sep 7 2019 (Firefox 79), this is no longer the case. Must have been a mistake in FF 51.**

---

This question is for the Firefox devs/pros out there. I can't find any info on this.

I've longed assumed XMLHttpRequest (XHR) and similar APIs such as the new Fetch API are **not supposed to work locally** (i.e. file uri), and only work on http or https uri scheme. It's supposed to be some big security risk.

In the past, the only way to circumvent this in Firefox was changing `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` to `false` in `about:config`. To my surprise, I can use both XHR and Fetch API without changing that setting in the latest Firefox.

Why does it start working out of nowhere on Firefox 51.0.1? Is this a bug, a new standard, or some vendor-specific thing? Is Chrome going to follow along with this?

To see what I mean, create an index.htm with some JS code and a test.txt with some text, and open the index.htm in Firefox locally.

Put this in the HTML:

```
<script>fetch("test.txt").then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
}).then(function(text) {
    alert(text);
});</script>
```

In Firefox it should show an alert box with the contents of the text file. In Chrome/Canary, it will complain:

> Fetch API cannot load file:///R:/test/test.txt. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

Comment: If the page is served locally (from your harddrive, using the `file://` protocol), it usually *can* access other local files.

Comment: They only accept requests to the same directory and its subdirectories, you can't go up one level, so security risks are mitigated. IIRC, Chrome had a similar behavior on windows OS when request were made from Desktop directory. I don't think neither behaviors are specified.

Comment: From [specs](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#basic-fetch) *"For now, unfortunate as it is, file and ftp URLs are left as an exercise for the reader."*  So implementations are free to do it as they like.

Comment: Not a definitive answer, but the intro paragraph to fetch implies that it should work for any resource, local and over the network "The Fetch API provides an interface for fetching resources (including across the network)". I sure hope Chrome fixes their browser too, because FireFox fetching resources as expected is much appreciated for local debugging.